# Network usage monitoring per device

Tags: router, bandwidth

I have LTE modem connected via ethernet to TP-Link archer ax20. I have 400GB monthly limit and i see that from some time internet usage increase. I want to start monitoring internet usage by device to identify most internet consuming devices. I don't see such option in router. Do you know how to do this? I have raspberry pi but not sure if it will help.

Edit: I'm wondering if this is possible to configure VPN on rasbperry and then set it on the router. Maybe then monitoring will be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather not bother to search for such an option on the home-grade hardware like your router. The feature you're asking for is a typical for professional routers, starting with Mikrotik devices; they have various counters and ability to send network flow information to collector server, where it can be accounted and graphed. So look for the device that supports SNMP counters and/or NetFlow export.

Also, you can try to install alternate firmware called OpenWRT if it's exists for your router model; that could bring you some of those features at the expense of losing support (and, probably, warranty) from the HW vendor and losing some performance (not all HW features are supported by the OpenWRT). There are [several solutions](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/friendly-traffic-monitor-per-ip-plus-historical/30515/4) like this for it.

Comment: There is no OpenWRT on my router. Also i don't want to buy new expensive router only to have network usage monitoring.